# VBA to select specified date range in pivot table filter

Tags: vba

I am trying to automate selection of dates in the report filter section of pivot table using vba. The idea is that the user puts in the start and end date before running the macro.  The code will first clear all filters and then select all dates that appear between the specified dates. I have the below code which works fine as long as there is data present for specified dates but throws an error when there is no data.
Any help for a work around of the error will be highly appreciated.

Code:

```
Sub PivotFilter()
Dim pvtF As PivotField
Dim pvtI As PivotItem
Dim StartDate As Date
Dim EndDate As Date

Sheets("Report").Activate
StartDate = Cells(2, 3)
EndDate = Cells(4, 3)

Worksheets("Pivots").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Date Received").ClearAllFilters
Set pvtF = Worksheets("Pivots").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Date Received")

For Each pvtI In pvtF.PivotItems
     If DateValue(pvtI.Name) >= StartDate And DateValue(pvtI.Name) <= EndDate Then
         pvtI.Visible = True
     Else
         pvtI.Visible = False
     End If
Next pvtI

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not that's actually 'proper' behavior.  A pivot table can't have all items with visible set to false otherwise excel throws an error.

You can check the # of visible items of a pivot field using the `.VisibleItems.Count` property.

As a bit of kludge you can create a last entry in your table with a clearly invalid date like  "Dec 31, 2099" and use the above property so it's the last one showing in your pivot table without incurring an error.  With that entry and changing `pvtI.Visible = False` in your code to this:

```
If pvtF.VisibleItems.Count <> 1 Then pvtI.Visible = False
```

at least you'll get rid of the error while showing a date that's clearly not in the range.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Amorpheuses.

Comment: I am not sure where the rest of my comment disappeared lol. I can't create another entry as the data is based on external connection and is refreshed every time the report is run. I can't move the date field from pivot report filter to rows or columns either as I am using 'getpivotdata' formula to extract the numbers from the pivot. Its basically a stickly situation...

Comment: Yes, not sure what your options are.  Was hoping someone else would also post so at least I'd see how others deal with this.